# How Can I remove ViewPager Indicator

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

I use actionbarsherlock. I dont want to show indicator like facebook. I want to use only icon on customactionbar.xml but i dont remove indicator.

My mainpage.xml;

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical">
        <fragment
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and My class;

```
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        View absview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customactionbar, null);
        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(absview);

        TabControlListener myTabListener = new TabControlListener(this, _viewPager);
        myTabListener.addTabChangedListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab_vehicledetail = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
        myTabListener.addTab(tab_vehicledetail,FragmentDeviceDetail.class,null);
        tab_vehicledetail.setTabListener(myTabListener);

        ActionBar.Tab tab_Notify = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
        myTabListener.addTab(tab_Notify,FragmentDeviceDetail.class,null);
        tab_Notify.setTabListener(myTabListener);

        ActionBar.Tab tab_LastPosition = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
        myTabListener.addTab(tab_LastPosition,FragmentDeviceDetail.class,null);
        tab_LastPosition.setTabListener(myTabListener);
```

[a Now http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/9012/screenshot7886652570341.png](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/9012/screenshot7886652570341.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a PagerTabStrip class, but instead of using PagerTabStrip you can use PagerTitleStrip will reduce the work greatly.

if you wanted to use pagerTabStrip still, you can change the color of the tab indicator. change it to your tabstrip background color.